# Linking to wpf clickonce app's .application file in a webpage

Tags: .net, wpf, clickonce

I want to link to my ClickOnce application's **.application** file instead of **setup.exe**. But when I do `<A HREF="http://url/myapp.application"></A>CLICK HERE`, and click on the link, it just prints the xml contents of the **.application** file.

Is there a way to actually run the .application file from a webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've run into this problem in the the past, it's typically because I needed to [set up some MIME types for the ClickOnce files on the web server](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/06/12/mime-types-for-clickonce-deployment/).

These would be the basic ClickOnce MIME types...

```
.application = application/x-ms-application 
.manifest = application/x-ms-manifest 
.deploy = application/octet-stream
```